# Group small values in a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a Pie chart from a dictionary using Python's matplotlib, I get some classes that are too mashed together because of their small size. Is there a way to group the smallest values together and maybe plot them in a separate pie chart (or graduated bar) using python?

Here is the code I used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

dic = {'class a': 26.9,
       'Class b': 18,
       'Class c': 16.8,
       'Class d': 13,
       'Class e': 8.83,
       'Class f': 5.97,
       'Class g': 3.59,
       'Class h': 2.01,
       'Class i': 1.42,
       'Class j': 1.09,
       'Class k': 0.903,
       'Class l': 0.873,
       'Class m': 0.28,
       'Class n': 0.24,
       'Class o': 0.112}

labels = dic.keys()
sizes = dic.values()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
'''
```

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to group the classes which ever are less than certain percentage and show it in a separate pie chart?

Comment: @Toros91that's exactly it.

Comment: you can use a threshold and separate them into 2 data-frames. Plot them separately

Comment: @Toros91 Can you please share how to that?

Comment: Do you have this dictionary in the form of a dataframe?

Comment: I can use pandas `import pandas as pd` and convert it `df = pd.DataFrame(list(dic.items()))`.

Comment: Is this something which you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

An idea would be to group the smaller slices together by grouping all the classes whose value is beneath a certain threshold, let's say in this case 2, and summing up their values.

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

dic = {'Class a': 26.9,
       'Class b': 18,
       'Class c': 16.8,
       'Class d': 13,
       'Class e': 8.83,
       'Class f': 5.97,
       'Class g': 3.59,
       'Class h': 2.01,
       'Class i': 1.42,
       'Class j': 1.09,
       'Class k': 0.903,
       'Class l': 0.873,
       'Class m': 0.28,
       'Class n': 0.24,
       'Class o': 0.112}

# group together all elements in the dictionary whose value is less than 2
# name this group 'All the rest'
import itertools
newdic={}
for key, group in itertools.groupby(dic, lambda k: 'All the rest' if (dic[k]<2) else k):
     newdic[key] = sum([dic[k] for k in list(group)])   

labels = newdic.keys()
sizes = newdic.values()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', explode=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.1), startangle=0)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: Group smaller slices in pie chart]

If it is important to show the values for the smaller slices, just plot a table with the missing data to the side.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution:

I'm attaching the new code in which I split the data using a threshold and then plot them separately into 2 pie charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')

dic = [{'class a': 26.9,
       'Class b': 18,
       'Class c': 16.8,
       'Class d': 13,
       'Class e': 8.83,
       'Class f': 5.97,
       'Class g': 3.59,
       'Class h': 2.01,
       'Class i': 1.42,
       'Class j': 1.09,
       'Class k': 0.903,
       'Class l': 0.873,
       'Class m': 0.28,
       'Class n': 0.24,
       'Class o': 0.112}]

labels = dic.keys()
sizes = dic.values()

#converting the data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
dft = df.transpose()

dft.columns = ['Value']
dft['Class'] = dft.index

#defining the threshold 
threshold = 5
dft_subset1 =  dft[dft['Value'] <= threshold]
dft_subset2 =  dft[dft['Value'] > threshold]

plot1 = dft_subset1.plot.pie(y='Value', figsize=(5, 5))
plot2 = dft_subset2.plot.pie(y='Value', figsize=(5, 5))
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Is it possible to move the pie chart legend out of the circle?

Comment: Never tried it, will need to do some research.